# ¿Cómo puedo entrar en una carpeta e ignorar el resto de archivos utilizando .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Trabajo con Gulp y tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo hacer para que solo se suba el "contenido" de app.

Sé que podría iniciar el proyecto en GitHub desde app ya directamente, pero ya es por curiosidad de cómo se podría hacer. ¿Se os ocurre alguna manera?

Comment: En `.gitignore` puedes poner nombres de carpetas, además de nombres de ficheros. No obstante tienes que configurar el `.gitignore` antes de haber metido al repositorio contenidos de esas capretas, pues si los metiste antes seguirán estando bajo control de versiones aún si los pones después en `.gitignore`. Para evitarlo tendrías que hacer un `git rm --cached` de los que ya no quieras seguir.

Comment: @abulafia  intentare probarlo cuando empiece un nuevo proyecto, gracias por contestar tan rápido.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer. Si ya tienes algo que git está trackeando y lo quieres quitar con `.gitignore`, tienes que quitar esos ficheros primero del repo o quitar el repo completamente y volver a subirlo cuando `.gitignore` esté bien formado. ¿Qué es lo que quieres trackear y qué no?

Comment: @FranMoya lo que quiero es que cuando yo cree un repositorio y tenga configurado el .gitignore en vez de ver  https://image.ibb.co/dzRuSd/Captura.png ver directamente los archivos en la raíz sin ver la carpeta app.

Comment: @MarioGodoySalamanca Ah, no. Para eso el repositorio debe crearse dentro de la carpeta `app`

Comment: muchas gracias @abulafia es que tenia dudas de si se podría hacer, ahora mismo doy por cerrada la pregunta ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade un `.gitignore` a cada subcarpeta que no sea app

```
*
!.gitignore
```

significa "ignora todo menos a tí misno".

Si tienes versionada toda la carpeta quítala con `git rm --cached carpeta` y luego vuelve a versionar sus `.gitignore` con  `git add -f carpeta/.gitignore`.

La otra opción es añadir manualmente cada subcarpeta en el `.gitignore` de la raíz del proyecto, pero la gracia de manejar `.gitignore` dentro de cada carpeta es que la carpeta misma queda en control de versiones y al hacer un deploy te ahorras el paso de crearla o recrearla, comprobar que tengas permisos y que la carpeta no exista, etc.

Comment: Porque no me funciona a mi este patrón, quiero decir quiero ignorar un directorio log, pero dentro de log tengo tres carpetas con contenido de los logs que quiero mantener (solo los directorios nginx, cron y symfony), pero he metido .gitkeep, pero no se mantienen, no he conseguido el efecto que quiero, solo o todo o nada

Comment: Si dejaste .gitignore dentro de cada subcarpeta de logs prueba `git add -f log/*/. gitignore`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo `.gitignore` debes agregar todos los `paths` que no se subiran a tu repositorio remoto.

Ejemplo:

```
html
img
js
node_modules
scss
```

Ya con eso estas restringiendo el acceso de `git` a esas carpetas, haciendo que solo este disponible tu folder app para subir juntos con los archivos de la raiz.

Espero que te haya servido mi respuesta, si es así dale un +1. Saludos